# Need advice on connecting Expo mobile app to Node server on Heroku

Tags: react-native, heroku, expo

I am developing a mobile app in React Native with Expo. The app uses a Node server to obtain data from a MongoDB database.

When I run the server locally on my system, and I access the server through a localtunnel URL from the mobile app that is running on Expo on my iPhone, then all is well. I get back the data I requested from the DB.

If I switch the mobile app to use the same server running on Heroku, and send the same axios request to the server, I do not get back the requested data. Instead, I receive what looks like  an index.html file. I get the same file whatever request I send.

Comment: It sounds like the is in your server, if you try to retrieve the data from postman (or another tool), do you get the correct data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the server code. I was initializing the client and static routes before the api routes. This meant that all external requests never got to the api routes but were handled by the client instead. That was why I always got the client index.html file as a response.

I did not work this out by myself but used a resource on Upwork which turned out to be a very useful site and well worth a reasonable rate for one hour's work.